# Redesigning our searchbar

Tags: forms, user-expectation, search, input-fields

Our users are having trouble with our search bar. They don't realize they need to click the search icon to start searching. To make it clearer, I've come up with three solutions:

A. Replace the icon with a text button that says 'search.'

B. Replace the icon with a text button that says 'search' and add a magnifying glass before the input text as a visual clue.

C. Add the text 'search' next to the magnifying glass in the button.

We need to choose one of these options quickly. Which one do you think provides the clearest solution?

[image]

Comment: Why "they need to click the search icon to start searching"? Isn't it enough to start typing?

Comment: @Danielillo It is clear enough that they can type, but not clear enough they have to press the icon button in order to do the search

Comment: It sounds like you're blaming users for not understanding something, when the problem is actually with your app - you should design the app to be intuitive to them, not design it 'wrong' and then try to make the wrong bit a little less-wrong. If users want to just search by typing then let them. Doesn't 'ENTER' trigger the search too? If not, why not implement autosuggest as they type?

Answer (score 3):

'option D': press 'enter'
type search string, press return... simple.
as a 'user', i dislike, very much, having to 'click' so much. keyboard, mouse, keyboard, mouse, mouse, keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is showing the search results as the user type their query into the search bar, in this way the user will click on the appropriate result or will be forced to press enter or click on a button to close the pop-up field

[image]

Comment: Sorry but it's not, the solution to my question is one of the 3 options I've provided. I will spare you all the details why we can't do it Google's way.

Answer (score 0):

We've chosen option C because we have users with reading difficulties, and therefore, we need to include a visual cue on the button.